# Trying to check Room DB from RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-room

I am trying to insert, delete and check my Room DB from the RecyclerView adapter but i cant get it done properly, because its like the adapter resetting the items all the time.

The basic functionality i am looking for, is to add an item directly from the RecyclerView Adapter to the DB.

Even though i insert and delete to the DB, i can't keep the status of my togglebutton checked or not depending the existence of each item in the DB.

[image]
[image]

PS dont mind all this logging...

Here 's my adapter

```
public class MovieListRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListRvAdapter.MoviesViewHolder>  {
private Context mContext;
private List<Movie> mMovies;
private static RvClickListener listener;
private boolean isInFavsAlready;
private static String LOG_TAG = MovieListRvAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public interface RvClickListener{
     void rvClickListener(View v, int position);
}

public void swapData(List<Movie> movies)
{
    if(movies == null || movies.size()==0)
        return;
    if (mMovies != null && mMovies.size()>0)
        mMovies.clear();
    mMovies.addAll(movies);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public MovieListRvAdapter(Context c, List<Movie> myMovieData, RvClickListener listener) {
    this.mContext = c;
    this.mMovies =myMovieData;
    this.listener = listener;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MovieListRvAdapter.MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.movie_list_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    MoviesViewHolder viewHolder = new MoviesViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieListRvAdapter.MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = this.mMovies.get(position);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(movie.getPoster_path())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .into(holder.moviePosterIv);
    holder.movieTitleTv.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.ratingBar.setRating(Float.valueOf(movie.getVote_average())/2);
    holder.movieReleaseDateTv.setText(modifyDateLayout(movie.getRelease_date()));
     boolean bool =isMovieInFavorites(movie);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "isMovieInFavorites " +bool + " " +movie.getTitle());
    if(bool){
        holder.favButton.setChecked(true);

    }else{
        holder.favButton.setChecked(false);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return (null != mMovies ? mMovies.size() : 0);
}

/**
 * Cache of the children views for a list item.
 */
public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView moviePosterIv;
    TextView movieTitleTv;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    TextView movieReleaseDateTv;
    ToggleButton favButton;

    public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        moviePosterIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster_path);
        movieTitleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitleListItem);
        movieReleaseDateTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieReleaseDate);
        favButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int position = getLayoutPosition();
                final Movie movie = mMovies.get(position);
                if (isChecked && !isMovieInFavorites(movie)){
                final AppDatabase mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(mContext);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "isMovieInFavorites " +isMovieInFavorites(movie));
                AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mDb.movieDao().insertMovie(movie);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " " + movie);
                    }
                });
                    favButton.setChecked(true);
                }
                else if (!isChecked){
                    final AppDatabase mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(mContext);
                    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mDb.movieDao().deleteMovie(movie);
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "movie deleted " + movie);
                        }
                    });
                    favButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MovieDetailsActivity.class);
        Movie movie = mMovies.get(clickedPosition);
        i.putExtra(MovieDetailsActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, movie);
        context.startActivity(i);
        listener.rvClickListener(v, clickedPosition);
    }
}

public boolean isMovieInFavorites(Movie movie) {
    final AppDatabase mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(mContext);
    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int dbMovieID = mDb.movieDao().searchFavsByMovieID(movie.getId());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "result of " + dbMovieID + " " + movie.getTitle());
            if(dbMovieID !=0){
                isInFavsAlready = true;

            }else{
                isInFavsAlready= false;
            }
        }
    });
```

//        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "result of method1 " + isInFavsAlready + " " + movie.getTitle());
        return isInFavsAlready;
    }

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM moviesTable ORDER BY id")
LiveData<List<Movie>> loadAllMovies();

@Query("SELECT * FROM moviesTable WHERE id = :id")
LiveData<Movie> loadMovieById(int id);

@Query("SELECT id FROM moviesTable WHERE id = :id")
int searchFavsByMovieID(int id);

@Query("SELECT id FROM moviesTable WHERE id = :id")
LiveData<Integer> searchFavsByMovieIDLive(int id);

@Insert
void insertMovie(Movie movie);

@Query("DELETE FROM moviesTable WHERE movieId = :movieID")
void deleteByID(int movieID);

@Delete
void deleteMovie(Movie movie);
```

}

Comment: Please add your movieDao.

Comment: just did, check it out! thanks

Comment: are you calling notifydatasetchanged after getting proper data from DB room

Comment: I faced the same problem. I couldn't find a solution. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this is a LiveData issue.  I did this project over a year ago before LiveData was around.  Last weekend I updated to use Room and LiveData.  I ran across this exact same problem.  [Here's the commit](https://github.com/BakonJarser/PopularMovies/commit/34976254b5cebbb86f011c289faeceb9f841d505) where the fix was made.  I store all of the movies in the DB and have a column that stores whether it is a favorite. Unfortunately I did quite a bit of refactoring in this commit but I think the relevant part is here (ignore the awful method name, it's because my network calls are a mess):

```
public boolean isFavoriteAlreadyInBackground(int movieId) {
    //  old code
    //    LiveData<Movie> movie = movieDao.getMovie(movieId);
    //    return movie.getValue() != null && movie.getValue().getFavorite();
        //new code
        Movie movie = movieDao.getMovie(movieId);
        return movie != null && movie.getFavorite();
    }
```

When I was checking the LiveData Movie the value of isFavorite was being set back to false so I started checking a non-live data version of the db object and it had the correct value.  I'm sure my project looks quite a bit different then yours but feel free to look through it and borrow any parts that will work for you, although it's very much a work in progress.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your function `isMovieInFavorites`.
This return statement `return isInFavsAlready;` is triggered before Room finishes its query (your query is run in io thread). So what you can do here is to wait until the query is finished before updating your UI

```
public void isMovieInFavorites(Movie movie) {
    final AppDatabase mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(mContext);
    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int dbMovieID = mDb.movieDao().searchFavsByMovieID(movie.getId());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "result of " + dbMovieID + " " + movie.getTitle());
            if(dbMovieID !=0){
                isInFavsAlready = true;
                mContext.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    holder.favButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }else{
                isInFavsAlready= false;
                mContext.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    holder.favButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```